# C++ Remove duplicated from an array

Tags: c++, arrays

Thanks for the help.

I have to adjust a function that will remove duplicates from an array. Currently, I'm getting weird output that I don't even understand and every time I attempt to cleanse the function of duplicates, i'm not getting the desired effect. Here is the code.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream> // For cout and cin
#include <string>   // For string objects
#include "Set.h"    // For ADT Set
using namespace std;

int main()
{

  //Creating a set to hold our numbers
  Set<int> a_set;

  //Checking if a_set is empty
  cout << "This is the empty set, and IsEmpty() returns "
    << a_set.IsEmpty() << endl;

  //creating an empty array
  int Array[] = {1};

  //Checking if the set now has a single items
  cout << "This set should have a single item, and a_set.Contains "
    << a_set.Contains(Array[1]) << endl;

  //Removing the item placed in a_set.
  a_set.Remove(Array[1]);

  //Verifying that the set is empty again.
  cout << "This is the empty set, and IsEmpty() returns "
    << a_set.IsEmpty() << " The set is now empty and ready for values." << endl;    


  //Adding items in order given
  a_set.Add(Array[1]);
  a_set.Add(Array[10]);
  a_set.Add(Array[3]);
  a_set.Add(Array[10]);
  a_set.Add(Array[5]);    
  a_set.Add(Array[10]);

  //Getting current size of a_set
  int size = a_set.GetCurrentSize();
  cout << "The Array should be size=4. Size = " << size << endl;

  //Checking that the items that we placed in the set are correct
  cout << "Number 1 should be pressent in a_set. Return: " 
    << a_set.Contains(Array[1]) << endl;

  cout << "Number 3 should be pressent in a_set. Return: " 
    << a_set.Contains(Array[3]) << endl;

  cout << "Number 5 should be pressent in a_set. Return: " 
    << a_set.Contains(Array[5]) << endl;

  cout << "Number 10 should be pressent in a_set. Return: " 
    << a_set.Contains(Array[10]) << endl;

int v = 0;
do
{
    cout << Array[v] << endl;
    v++;
}while (v < 7);
   return 0;

}; // end main
```

Now here is my function. This is prior to me even trying to remove the duplicates....

```
function.cpp

#include "Set.h"
#include <cstddef>

template<class ItemType>
Set<ItemType>::Set() : item_count_(0), max_items_(kDefaultSetSize_)
{
}  // end default constructor

template<class ItemType>
int Set<ItemType>::GetCurrentSize() const
{
  return item_count_;
}  // end getCurrentSize

template<class ItemType>
bool Set<ItemType>::IsEmpty() const
{
  return item_count_ == 0;
}  // end isEmpty

// Made changes to deny duplicate items in an array.
template<class ItemType>
bool Set<ItemType>::Add(const ItemType& new_entry)
{
  bool has_room_to_add = item_count_ < max_items_;
  if (has_room_to_add)
  {
    items_[item_count_] = new_entry;
    item_count_++;
  }  // end if

  return has_room_to_add;
}  // end add

template<class ItemType>
bool Set<ItemType>::Remove(const ItemType& an_entry)
{
  int located_index = GetIndexOf(an_entry);
  bool can_remove_item = !IsEmpty() && (located_index > -1);
  if (can_remove_item)
    {
      item_count_--;
      items_[located_index] = items_[item_count_];
    }  // end if
  return can_remove_item;
}  // end remove

template<class ItemType>
void Set<ItemType>::Clear()
{
  item_count_ = 0;
}  // end clear

template<class ItemType>
int Set<ItemType>::GetFrequencyOf(const ItemType& an_entry) const
{
  int frequency = 0;
  int search_index = 0;
  while (search_index < item_count_)
    {
      if (items_[search_index] == an_entry)
    {
      frequency++;
    }  // end if

      search_index++;
    }  // end while

   return frequency;
}  // end getFrequencyOf

template<class ItemType>
bool Set<ItemType>::Contains(const ItemType& an_entry) const
{
  return GetIndexOf(an_entry) > -1;
}  // end contains

template<class ItemType>
vector<ItemType> Set<ItemType>::ToVector() const
{
  vector<ItemType> bag_contents;
  for (int i = 0; i < item_count_; i++)
    bag_contents.push_back(items_[i]);
  return bag_contents;
}  // end toVector

template<class ItemType>
int Set<ItemType>::GetIndexOf(const ItemType& target) const
{
  bool found = false;
  int result = -1;
  int search_index = 0;
  // if the bag is empty, item_count is zero, so loop is skipped
  while (!found && (search_index < item_count_))
    {
      if (items_[search_index] == target)
    {
      found = true;
      result = search_index;
    } 
      else
    {
      search_index++;
    }  // end if
    }  // end while
  return result;
}  // end getIndexOf
```

*.h file

```
#ifndef TEACH_CSCI235_BAGADT_BAG_H_
#define TEACH_CSCI235_BAGADT_BAG_H_

#include "SetInterface.h"

template<class ItemType>
class Set : public SetInterface<ItemType>
{
 public:
  Set();
  int GetCurrentSize() const;
  bool IsEmpty() const;
  bool Add(const ItemType& new_entry);
  bool Remove(const ItemType& an_entry);
  void Clear();
  bool Contains(const ItemType& an_ntry) const;
  int GetFrequencyOf(const ItemType& an_entry) const;
  vector<ItemType> ToVector() const; 

 private:
  static const int kDefaultSetSize_ = 6;  
  ItemType items_[kDefaultSetSize_]; // array of bag items
  int item_count_;                    // current count of bag items 
  int max_items_;                 // max capacity of the bag

  // Returns either the index of the element in the array items that
  // contains the given target or -1, if the array does not contain 
  // the target.
  int GetIndexOf(const ItemType& target) const;   
};  // end Set

#include "Set.cpp"

#endif  // TEACH_CSCI235_BAGADT_BAG_H_
```

My output is:

```
This is the empty set, and IsEmpty() returns 1
This set should have a single item, and a_set.Contains 1
This is the empty set, and IsEmpty() returns 1 The set is now empty and ready for values.
The Array should be size=4. Size = 6
Number 1 should be pressent in a_set. Return: 1
Number 3 should be pressent in a_set. Return: 1
Number 5 should be pressent in a_set. Return: 1
Number 10 should be pressent in a_set. Return: 1
1
0
42563728
1
2056807160
32767
42563728
```

I have tried to implement a while loop and a for loop in the function.cpp (as per the assignment) and haven't been able to get anything to work. Can you please point me in the right direction as I feel that I'm missing something.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you initializing 'Array'?

Comment: If you aren't initializing Array, its contents will be undefined. This means you can get any arbitrary values out of it. You may or may not notice your program's output changes each time you run it.

Comment: @RonDahlgren-  Are you suggesting that I move the array after I check if a_set is empty then add the values like int Array[] = {1, 10, 3, 10, 5, 10}; and then go about my day attempting to remove the duplicates?

Comment: There are a lot of syntactic problems with the code you have posted. That makes it difficult to identify what your particular error is. First, the 'Array' variable needs to have a value. You are declaring it, but never initializing it. Second, where is 'a_set' declared and what type is it?  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you updated to a complete listing of your code, it seems that the issue is use of values outside of the bounds of your array (the variable `Array`). In C++, there is no safety mechanism to prevent you from accessing uninitialized memory.

For instance, given the following snippet (adapted from your code):

```
int main(int, char**) {
  /* Notice I only specify one element */
  int array[] = { 1 };

  int v = 0;
  do {
      std::cout << array[v] << std::endl;
      v++;
  } while (v < 7);

  return 0;
}
```

I get this output:

```
rdahlgren@athas:~/work/cpp $ g++ main.cpp 
rdahlgren@athas:~/work/cpp $ ./a.out
1
32767
0
3
4196544
0
372508672
```

The 'strange' values here are from uninitialized memory. Its contents are undefined. Instead, you should define an 11 element array. I say 11 elements because you access index 10 in your code, and C++ uses zero-based array indices.

If I update my snippet to this:

```
int main(int, char**) {
  /* Now I specify 11 elements */
  int array[] = { 
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
    6, 7, 8, 9, 10
  };

  int v = 0;
  do {
      std::cout << array[v] << std::endl;
      v++;
  } while (v < 7);

  return 0;
}
```

I get the following (more sane) result:

```
rdahlgren@athas:~/work/cpp $ g++ main.cpp 
rdahlgren@athas:~/work/cpp $ ./a.out
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Take care to always initialize variables before using them in C++. Failing to do so can lead to very serious and difficult to detect bugs.

To further illustrate the difference, here's a complete example that shows statically allocating an array, then initializing it in separate steps. In the code above I use the array literal syntax to initialize it.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char**) {
  const unsigned int arrayLength = 5;
  int array[arrayLength]; // <-- allocated, but uninitialized

  std::cout << "Uninitialized values:\n";
  for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i) {
    std::cout << "Array index " << i << " is " << array[i] << std::endl;
  }

  // Now we can initialize it / insert values / whatever
  for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i) {
    array[i] = i * 10; // Times ten just for fun
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; ++i) {
    std::cout << "Array index " << i << " is " << array[i] << std::endl;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. One last question: if I had to initialize an empty array and then add integers to the array, what would I have to do in this scenario considering that I have to pass the values to a function to add the variables. P.S. I'm actually late with my assignment and just need to learn where my lack of knowledge is. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'empty' here. An array is either initialized or uninitialized. I'll add another example

Comment: Thank you again for pointing me in the right direction, I actually figured it out. I was always addressing the index of the array not assigning values. In the beginning, I could have left the array uninitialized but during the a_set.Add(Array[0]) step, I had to assign a value to the index that I was calling.