# how to remove duplicates from the array

Tags: arrays, c

I have multiple arrays and I need to return the value of the order the customer enters, the arrays have duplicated values so even after sorting them from low to high when the order is placed he'll take the duplicated value. how can I remove the duplicated?
ex. int testA1[] = { 25000, 20000, 29499, 10000, 20000, 29000, 25000, 20000 , 25000 , 10000 };
int order1 = 3; <-- it should print out 29000but instead it prints 25000

```
#include<stdio.h>

int lowestPrice(int array[], int size, int order){
    int tempArray[size];
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        tempArray[i] = array[i];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (size_t j = i; j < size; j++)
            if (tempArray[j] < tempArray[i]) {
                int tmp = tempArray[i];
                tempArray[i] = tempArray[j];
                tempArray[j] = tmp;
            }

    int j = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size -1; i++){
        if(tempArray[i] != tempArray[i+1])
        {
            tempArray[j] = tempArray[i];                
            j++;    
        } 
        tempArray[j] = tempArray[i-1];
    }   
       
    if(order > size || order < 0){
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        return tempArray[order];    
    }
}
```

Comment: You should take a look to the similar questions here in stackoverflow (it is better for you if you learn how to adapt other people's solution to your problem), here one example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28757237/c-remove-duplicated-from-an-array

Comment: After sorting and removing duplicates, the array is `10000, 20000, 25000, 29000, 29499`, so array[3] is 29000.

Comment: thanks!! I'll take a look at them

Comment: after sorting and remove duplicates it'll be 10000, 20000, 25000, 29000, 29499 but I need to remove duplicates first or it'll still 25000

Comment: The question says you expect the result to be `25000`. But the correct result for `order=3` is `29000`

Comment: Remember that indexes start at 0, not 1.

Comment: sorry I misplaced them it prints out 25000 and it is supposed to be 29000

Comment: The easy way to debug this is to print the array after sorting, and print the array after removing duplicates.

Comment: can u specify the issue pls? I'm still a beginner

Answer (score 0):

```
main(void){
int testA1[] = { 25000, 20000, 29499, 10000, 20000, 29000, 25000, 20000 , 25000 , 10000 };
int size = sizeof(testA1) / sizeof(int); //size of array
// if your orders are only going to be positive numbers as it should for your wealth :
// (change duplicate value by -1)
for (int i = 0; i < size ; ++i)
{
    int is_duplicate = testA1[i];
    if (is_duplicate == -1)
        continue ;
    int j = i +1;
    while ( j < size) {
        if (is_duplicate == testA1[j])
            testA1[j] = -1;
        ++j;
    }
}
// sort it ;) :
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        for (size_t j = i; j < size; j++)
            if (testA1[j] < testA1[i]) {
                int tmp = testA1[i];
                testA1[i] = testA1[j];
                testA1[j] = tmp;
            }
    int new_index = 0;
    while (testA1[new_index] == -1)
        ++new_index;
// here is for you to see the new state (you can remove this part)
    for (int i = new_index; i < size; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", testA1[i]);
// now get your order price from the new index (index + your_desired_value) 
    return testA1[new_index + -->your_desired_value<--];
}
```